# Div dinámico de exec() PHP

Tags: php, exec

Estoy desarollando un proyecto y muchas partes son *on live*, os cuento:

```
$salida = exec($args);
```

Necesito realizar un div dinámico que se autorefresque cada vez que se ejecute una función que contiene un `exec();`.

Esto viene heredado de un *foreach* con lo cual cada vez que la variables `$salida` se ejecute, actualice el div con su contenido sin refrescar la página.

No sé si ha habido alguien que haya tenido este problema, pero he buscado bastante y no he encontrado nada.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hola JPerez. Vamos a ver, para empezar `exec()` es una función de PHP, por lo tanto del backend o parte del servidor. De primeras, no puedes hacer que cuando se "ejecute" la función avise para que se refresque el div, tendrías que enviar una petición cada X segundos al servidor para que se actualice. Por otro lado una variable no se "ejecuta", entiendo que te refieres a que cambie y `exec` solo devuelve la última línea de salida de lo ejecutado, si quieres recoger todo debes definir una variable salida como segundo parámetro `exec($path, $output)`

Comment: Hola @JoseFG ante todo gracias por la rápida respuesta. El codigo lo tengo tal cual lo pones, como se ejecuta el linux pongo un ejemplo `exec ('ping 192.168.1.XX 2>&1', $output);`.

Mi idea es que XX llegue desde 1 a 254 y que vaya mostrando cada vez que $output tenga un valor, lo muestre en cada linea por separado.